# How to get the total no of records after applying the Filter pipe in angular

Tags: angular

How to get the total no of records after applying the Filter pipe in angular.

Here is my sample code, I have tried but I am not getting the exact length of rows.

**my Component file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './Employee';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  public employees : Employee[];
  searchValue : string="";
  count : number = 0 ;
```

my Template code:

```
<label>Total number of Employees : </label>  
    <label id="count">{{count}}</label> 

    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees | namefilter: searchValue ; let count = index">

        <td #name{{employee.id}} id="name{{employee.id}}">{{employee.name}}</td>
        <td #loc{{employee.id}} id="loc{{employee.id}}">{{employee.location}}</td>
        <td #email{{employee.id}} id="email{{employee.id}}">{{employee.email}}</td>
        <td #mobile{{employee.id}} id="mobile{{employee.id}}">{{employee.mobile}}</td>
    </tr>
```

my Filter pipe code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from './employees/employee';

@Pipe({
  name: 'namefilter'
})
export class NamefilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(param1: Employee[], param2: string): object {

    if(!param1) 
     return [];
    if(!param2) return param1;
    var search = param2.toLowerCase();
    return param1.filter((a) =>
    {
      return a.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search);
    } );
    return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this using ViewChild. Try This:

```
<label>Total number of Employees : </label>  
    <label id="count">{{count}}</label>
```

In your Html:

```
<tr #myFilter *ngFor="let employee of employees | namefilter: searchValue ; let count = index">

    <td #name{{employee.id}} id="name{{employee.id}}">{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td #loc{{employee.id}} id="loc{{employee.id}}">{{employee.location}}</td>
    <td #email{{employee.id}} id="email{{employee.id}}">{{employee.email}}</td>
    <td #mobile{{employee.id}} id="mobile{{employee.id}}">{{employee.mobile}}</td>
</tr>
```

In your .ts:
    @ViewChildren('myFilter ') createdItems;

```
count : number = 0 ;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.count  = this.createdItems.toArray().length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you exact count

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eids9h

You need to keep a array or object for count in your component and pass the same from template to your pipe. In pipe set value according to filtered data

**Component**

```
filteredCount = { count: 0 };
```

this.filteredCount.count = this.employees.length

**Template**

```
<label>Total number of Employees : </label>  
    <label id="count">{{filteredCount.count}}</label> 

    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees | namefilter: searchValue : filteredCount">

        <td #name{{employee.id}} id="name{{employee.id}}">{{employee.name}}</td>
        <td #loc{{employee.id}} id="loc{{employee.id}}">{{employee.location}}</td>
        <td #email{{employee.id}} id="email{{employee.id}}">{{employee.email}}</td>
        <td #mobile{{employee.id}} id="mobile{{employee.id}}">{{employee.mobile}}</td>
    </tr>
```

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'namefilter'
})
export class NamefilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(param1: any[], param2: string,filteredCount:any): object {    
    if(!param1) 
     return [];
    if(!param2) return param1;
    var search = param2.toLowerCase();
    filteredCount.count = 0;

    return param1.filter((a) =>
    {

      if(a.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search)){
        filteredCount.count = filteredCount.count + 1
        return true
      }
    } );
    return null;
  }

}
```